# Get soap fault content with spring message resolver

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I'm using spring integration and SOAP to integrate an external system. I added a `SoapFaultMessageResolver` to an

```
      <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="mnpOutboundGateway"
                           request-channel="mnpWSRequestChannel"
                           reply-channel="mnpWSResponseChannel"
                           marshaller="mnpMarshaller"
                           unmarshaller="mnpMarshaller"
                           destination-provider="mnpUriProvider"
                           fault-message-resolver="mnpFaultResolver"
                           message-factory="mnpMessageFactory"/>

  <bean name="mnpFaultResolver" class="com.iquest.play.integration.mnp.MnpSoapFaultResolver">
```

now I have overrid
 `@Override
  public void resolveFault(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {...`

The question is, how can I get the Soap Message content (reason,error code) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to start from source of existing solution `SoapFaultMessageResolver`:

```
SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) message;
throw new SoapFaultClientException(soapMessage);
```

And furthe the source code (some parts) of that `SoapFaultClientException`:

```
SoapBody body = faultMessage.getSoapBody();
soapFault = body != null ? body.getFault() : null;
...
public QName getFaultCode() {
     return soapFault != null ? soapFault.getFaultCode() : null;
}
...

public String getFaultStringOrReason() {
     return soapFault != null ? soapFault.getFaultStringOrReason() : null;
}
```

I think it's enough from the question perspective.

Comment: I was trying to get it out of `WebServiceMessage`. Thank you very much for your help, already the 2nd time :)